# How do you create a VS single file generator with Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, vsx

I am trying to create a single file generator with Roslyn running with /rootsuffix Roslyn, but the usual IVsSingleFileGenerator does not seem to work - I cannot even hit a breakpoint in it. What should I do?

Comment: What Visual Studio are you using? VS 2015 doesn't require /rootsuffix Roslyn. You can just use /rootsuffix Exp instead.

Comment: I am using VS 2014 CTP update 3. If I do not need /rootsuffix Roslyn, how do I get a reference to the workspace?

Comment: Consider upgrading to the newer VS2015 Preview.

Answer (score 1):

To make your extension automatically deploy to the Roslyn hive, open your csproj file, and add `<VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix>roslyn</VSSDKTargetPlatformRegRootSuffix>`.

However, you don't actually need the Roslyn hive at all.

On VS2013, the Roslyn preview installed itself to the Roslyn hive.  However, Dev14 always uses Roslyn, regardless in every hive (Roslyn completely replaces the native language services).

Comment: I am using VS 2014, I am also planning to switch to 2015 very soon. So I understand that that usual /rootsuffix Exp will do the job. How do I get a reference to Roslyn Workspace from within the IVsSingleFileGenerator implementation?

Comment: @NickPolyak: There is no VS2014.  Do you mean the Dev14 CTP?

Comment: And, add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll, then import `VisualStudioWorkspace` from MEF.

Comment: VS2014 CTP update 3 that I use does not allow me to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll. I've added services to Microsoft.VisualStudion.Package.LanguageServices.14.dll and also     Microsoft.VisualStudion.Package.LanguageServices.12.dll instead, but none of them have VisualStudioWorkspace class

Comment: Look in Program Files\VS 14\IDE\Common7\Private Assemblies

Answer (score 0):

How are you arranging to install your VS extension into the Roslyn hive? By default building a VSIX and debugging from VS installs the VSIX into the Exp hive. That might be why your single file generator isn't being created.

Comment: I am only running it through a debugger with /rootsuffix Roslyn parameters.

Comment: How are you _deploying_ your VSIX to that hive though? AFAIK there is no supported way to do that.